Shorten Kotlin's output filenames
I'm looking for a way to shorten Kotlin's compiled filenames so instead of ClassName$InnerClassFunctionWhateverButAVeryLongName$1.class I'd like to make it shorter. Is there any way to do so?

How do you want to shorten it? The file name doesn't contain any redundant information. Even if you could do this, you would need to write your own class loader to load these classes because the system class loader will not recognise these short names. Why do you want to do this?

One idea I thought of is obfuscating the code using something like ProGuard. This usually creates shorter (but unreadable) class file names.

@Sweeper TBH I'm looking for something like Gradle plugin or compiler option to do so. The reason why I'd like to do it is that Encryptfs util limits the filename to 140 bytes instead of default 255 by ext4 and the existing project does not compile because of having files with longer names.

If readability isn’t a problem then I think ProGuard is a possible solution.

If you can compile your Kotlin code onto a non-encrypted file system first, then you can create a jar file with long file names and then put that jar file onto eCryptFS. It doesn't matter that file names inside the jar will exceed 144 bytes, as long as the jar file name itself doesn't.

Actually I've ended up with having another partition just for projects, that's encrypted with LUKS and thus doesn't imply filename restrictions. Cheers and thanks for help guys <3 Also for future reference I'd suggest posting your comments as answers, because well, they solve the problem.
